# How to fetch single records using case statements

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    e_id     NUMBER(10),
    e_value  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11,123);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11,123);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11,null);

COMMIT;
```

I want to fetch single record from the table `test_table` if any one of the value is `null` in the column `e_value` then it should print `No` else `Yes`

My Attempt:

```
SELECT e_id,
CASE 
WHEN e_value IS NULL THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'
END is_answer
FROM test_table;
```

Current Output:

```
+------+-----------+
| e_id | is_answer |
+------+-----------+
|   11 | Yes       |
|   11 | Yes       |
|   11 | No        |
+------+-----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+-----------+
| e_id | is_answer |
+------+-----------+
|   11 | No        |
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Do you care of the e_id or e_value of this row or just the matching is_answer?

Comment: Have you tried anything to get this? It is good practice to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the question.

Comment: Why do you want to use CASE statments ?

Comment: You did not include your SQL.  Maybe add a Where clause, `Where e_value is null`.

Comment: @ankyskywalkerYes I had tried but forgot to post that. Now I have added in the original question

Comment: @Gnqz No I need only e_id and evaluated column for which I am using CASE expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT e_id,
CASE 
WHEN count(e_id) = count(e_value) THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END is_answer
FROM test_table
GROUP BY e_id;
```

The count will return number of non-null values

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5286f872dd9a7b4e3fa9dfcffa791e38)*

Comment: note that if you're not too familiar with `GROUP BY` and you need to add additional attributes/columns to your select statement (example select e_id, description, color, case when ...) then you will need to add the same attributes to the group by, (example `group by e_id, description, color;`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting it into a CTE and then selecting from that

```
with tagged_is_answer AS(
SELECT e_id,
CASE 
WHEN e_value IS NULL THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'
END is_answer
FROM test_table;
),
ordered_tagged_is_answer as (
select e_id
,is_answer
,row_number() over(partition by e_id order by is_answer asc) is_answer_order 
from tagged_is_answer
)
select e_id,is_answer from ordered_tagged_is_answer where is_answer_order=1

/*will pick No's before Yes's*/
```

CTE's are created in-memory so make sure your table is not bigger than your memory.

Comment: Thanks for this but it is not necessary that I have to select is_answer ='No' everytime. There can be possibility of Yes. Can we have this using ```SELECT``` query only? As I need to join this conditions with another table

Comment: @Vicky Added a column for order to pick No's over Yes's

Answer (score 0):

Order by `e_value` with the `NULLS FIRST` and only get the first row:

```sql
SELECT e_id,
       CASE WHEN e_value IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END is_answer
FROM   test_table
ORDER BY e_value NULLS FIRST
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | E_ID | IS_ANSWER |
> | --- | --- |
> | 11 | No |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bfaf5e23d541197df5c9b0672ab8975d)*